# C# Generics Inheritance Problem

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, compiler-errors

I'd like to add different types of objects derived from one class with generics into a List of base type. I get this compile error

```
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ConsoleApplication1.Stable' to 'ConsoleApplication1.ShelterBase<ConsoleApplication1.AnimalBase>'   C:\Users\ysn\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 43  26  ConsoleApplication1
```

I can't see the problem could you provide me an alternative way of doing this kind of thing?

```
abstract class AnimalBase { public int SomeCommonProperty;}

abstract class ShelterBase<T> where T : AnimalBase
{
    public abstract List<T> GetAnimals();
    public abstract void FeedAnimals(List<T> animals);
}


class Horse : AnimalBase { }

class Stable : ShelterBase<Horse>
{
    public override List<Horse> GetAnimals()
    {
        return new List<Horse>();
    }

    public override void FeedAnimals(List<Horse> animals)
    {
        // feed them
    }
}


class Duck : AnimalBase { }

class HenHouse : ShelterBase<Duck>
{
    public override List<Duck> GetAnimals()
    {
        return new List<Duck>();
    }

    public override void FeedAnimals(List<Duck> animals)
    {
        // feed them
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ShelterBase<AnimalBase>> shelters = new List<ShelterBase<AnimalBase>>();

        ///////////////////////////// following two lines do not compile
        shelters.Add(new Stable()); 
        shelters.Add(new HenHouse());
        /////////////////////////////

        foreach (var shelter in shelters)
        {
            var animals = shelter.GetAnimals();
            // do sth with 'animals' collection
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of .Net are you using ?  If it's .Net 4 you need to look into Covariance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [contravariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx), but *only* if you change your abstract class to an interface and the return type of `GetAnimals` to an `IEnumerable<T>`, because `List<T>` doesn't support this feature.

Code that works:

```
abstract class AnimalBase { public int SomeCommonProperty;}

interface IShelterBase<out T> where T : AnimalBase
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAnimals();
}

class Horse : AnimalBase { }

class Stable : IShelterBase<Horse>
{
    public IEnumerable<Horse> GetAnimals()
    {
        return new List<Horse>();
    }
}

class Duck : AnimalBase { }

class HenHouse : IShelterBase<Duck>
{
    public IEnumerable<Duck> GetAnimals()
    {
        return new List<Duck>();
    }
}

void Main()
{
    List<IShelterBase<AnimalBase>> shelters = new List<IShelterBase<AnimalBase>>();

    shelters.Add(new Stable());
    shelters.Add(new HenHouse());

    foreach (var shelter in shelters)
    {
        var animals = shelter.GetAnimals();
        // do something with 'animals' collection
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel, thanks for your answer. This works great, but I have one new problem now. When I add the method
    **`void FeedAnimals(IEnumerable<T> animals);`**
to the interface **`IShelterBase`** it gives this compile error:
    _`Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'IShelterBase<T>.FeedAnimals(IEnumerable<T>)'. 'T' is covariant.`_

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason, why list doesn't support it either. As soon as T is an input and an output parameter, it doesn't work anymore. Please see the page about that topic as linked in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using covariance and contravariance, but your ShelterBase class needs to derive from an interface, since only interfaces can be co- or contravariant.  You list will need to be a `List<IShelterBase<T>>` and it should work.

[See here for more info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

To solve this particular problem you don't actually need covariance. When you consume animal lists, you still get `AnimalBase` through `IShelterBase<out T>` interface. Might as well expose a list of `AnimalBase` through the base class.

A better and cleaner design would be to make `GetAnimals` return a list of `AnimalBase`, and to create an overload in each shelter class to return a list of that particular animal.

```
abstract class ShelterBase<T> where T : AnimalBase
{
    public List<AnimalBase> GetAnimals(){return new List<AnimalBase>();}
}

class Stable : ShelterBase<Horse>
{
    public List<Horse> GetHorses(){return new List<Horse>();}
}
```

Another problem with this design is exposing a collection through the most derived type - i.e. `List`, as opposed to `IEnumerable` or `IList`. Seeing as you went into trouble of creating a class abstracting a collection of animals, you should really protect the inner collection by disallowing direct insert/delete ability. Once you do that, things become a bit easier. E.g. here is how I would solve this problem.

```
abstract class ShelterBase<T> where T : AnimalBase
{
    protected List<T> _Animals;
    public AnimalBase() {
       _Animals = CreateAnimalCollection();
    }

    protected abstract List<T> CreateAnimalCollection();
    public IEnumerable<AnimalBase> GetAnimals(){return _Animals.Cast<AnimalBase>();}

    //Add remove operations go here
    public void Add(T animal){_Animals.Add(animal);}
    public void Remove(T animal){_Animals.Remove(animal);}

}

class Stable : ShelterBase<Horse>
{
    protected override List<Horse> CreateAnimalCollection(){return new List<Horse>();}

    public IEnumerable<Horse> GetHorses(){return _Animals;}
}
```

You will notice that the internal collection of animals is never exposed as mutable list. This is good, as it allows you tighter control over its contents. The `Add` and `Remove` methods in the base shelter are a bit contrived in this example as they don't add anything extra over direct collection access, but you can add logic there - e.g. checking for maximum shelter size when adding or checking the animal age before removing it.

Answer (score 1):

An article on co and contra-variance in generics:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Comment: No it's not covariance things.

Comment: The article discusses both Co and Contra-variance in generics.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a similar problem.
All my entities derive from a base class and I created a method to return a concatenated list of ids. So created the method with generics and got some convert errors. Managed to cast the **generic T** to **Object** and Object to **BaseClass** and put some sort of validation just in case.

```
//Needs it generic to use in a lot of derived classes
private String ConcatIds<T>(List<T> listObj)
{
    String ids = String.Empty;

    foreach (T obj in listObj)
    {
        BaseEntity be = CastBack(obj);

        if (ids.Count() > 0)
            ids = ids + String.Format(", {0}", be.Id);
        else
            ids = be.Id.ToString();
    }

    return ids;
}

//I'll probably move it to the Base Class itself
private BaseEntity CastBack<T>(T genericObj)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    if (type.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity))
    {
        Object _obj = (Object)genericObj;
        return (BaseEntity)_obj;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Cannot convert {0} to BaseEntity", type.ToString()));
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
   public Int32 Id {get; set;}
}

public class AnyDerivedClass : BaseEntity
{
  // Lorem Ipsum
}

private void DoAnything(List<AnyDerivedClass> myList)
{
    String ids = this.ConcatIds<AnyDerivedClass>(myList);
}
```

**Edit:** After a while I needed to create more hierarchy level and sometimes cast back to parent or to grand parent. So I let my CastBack method more generic.

```
private B CastBack<T,B>(T genericObj)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    if (type.BaseType == typeof(B))
    {
        Object _obj = (Object)genericObj;
        return (B)_obj;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Cannot cast back {0}", type.ToString()));
    }
}
```