# Casting to Generic base class failing

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am failing to see why my attempt to cast to a generic base class is not working.

The basic structure of the code is as follows.

```
interface ICmd
{
}

class Context
{
}

class Cmd<TContext> : ICmd
    where TContext : Context
{
}

class MyContext : Context
{
}

class MyCmd : Cmd<MyContext>
{
}
```

So now I have an instance of ICmd and want to cast it to Cmd as follows

```
var base = cmd as Cmd<Context>
```

base is always null after this line is executed.

changing cast to be specific for the context only and it works.

```
var base = cmd as Cmd<MyContext>       -- this works ???
```

Hope I have provided enough information, is this a covariance\contravariance issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You may want to use [co- and contravariance](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305121028/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/).

The problem is that `Cmd<Context>` is **not** the base class of `Cmd<MyContext>`.

See this recent question for a more detailed answer: [C# Generics Inheritance Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909209/c-generics-inheritance-problem/5909257#5909257)

Answer (score 2):

What you need here is covariance. C# 4 currently does not allow variance for generic type  parameters in classes. If your interface doesn't need to allow using the `TContext` in any input positions, you can consider making the interface generic, and covariant in `TContext`:

```
interface ICmd<out TContext> where TContext : Context { }

class Cmd<TContext> : ICmd<TContext> where TContext : Context { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Cmd<MyContext> cmd = new Cmd<MyContext>();

    var foo = cmd as ICmd<Context>;
}
```