# Templated type problems

Tags: c#, generics

Below is a dumbed down snippet of code that I want to keep a list of requests in order to match them with responses.  I stripped so much code out of this to make it simple, that it probably does not make much sense.

The comments in the code below indicates the error.  What am I doing wrong with Templated types?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Request request = new Request();
        Response response = SendReceive<Response>(request);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static T SendReceive<T>(IMessage request) where T: IMessage
    {
        T results = default(T);

        OutstandingRequest<T> outstandingRequest = new OutstandingRequest<T>();
        _waitingForResponses.Add(outstandingRequest as OutstandingRequest<IMessage>);
        // Above line of code adds a null to the list because outstandingRequest (type OutstandingRequest<T>) 
        //is not of type OutstandingRequest(IMessage) even though T is restricted to be of type IMessage

        // Do stuff like send, and wait for a response, return results.

        return results;
    }
    static List<OutstandingRequest<IMessage>> _waitingForResponses = new List<OutstandingRequest<IMessage>>();

    public interface IMessage
    {
        void Qaax();
    }
    public class Request : IMessage
    {
        public void Qaax() { }
    }
    public class Response : IMessage
    {
        public void Qaax() { }
    }

    public class OutstandingRequest<T> where T : IMessage
    {
        public T Response { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978976/casting-to-generic-base-class-failing help?

Comment: @mjwills I believe it is good duplicate - closing (so OP can read and if necessary update this question to clarify they did not understood something).