# Create Instance of type using base class with generics

Tags: c#, generics, activator

I've created a plugin system within my code, which loads types from DLLS.  I grab the type I want from the loaded DLL using this code;

```
var type = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath).GetTypes()
                    .FirstOrDefault(t =>
                        t.IsClass && t.IsSubclassOfRawGeneric(typeof(DespatchBasePlugin<>)));
```

*IsSubClassOfRawGeneric hunts down the base type as it is buried several classes down, the code works and the correct type is returned.*

I then create an instance of this class using Activator;

```
DespatchBasePlugin<XMLSettingBase> obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { logger }) as DespatchBasePlugin<XMLSettingBase>;
```

Unfortunately the cast on this line creates a null reference.  Removing the cast returns an instance of the class in question, but I need to store is as its base type.

This is the class being loaded(Shortened for brevity);

```
public class DHLPlugin : DespatchBasePlugin<UserSetting>
{
    public DHLPlugin(BaseForm logger) : base("DHL", logger)
    {
        this.order = 10;
    }
}
```

And this is the base class I want it to use(Note the class itself has a base class, it goes several layers deep);

```
public abstract class DespatchBasePlugin<TSettings> : DespatchBase<TSettings> where TSettings : XMLSettingBase, new()
```

The previous code used a base class with no generic assigned to it and worked absolutely fine. It looked like this;

```
DespatchBasePlugin obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object[] { logger }) as DespatchBasePlugin;
```

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb, please tell me what it is.

Edit - Not marked this as duplicate as I believe this is a better question/answer than the other which consists of a generic link to MSDN as the answer.  If this is not a correct way to use the duplicate system please let me know.

Comment: Can you show us the class declaration for the class it instantiates, and also the definition of `DespatchBasePlugin<>`?

Comment: Updated, thanks John.  I missed out the base classes of the base class, it goes about 4 levels deep, not sure if you need all of them?

Comment: I think that's enough. Let me find the correct SO post to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting to Generic base class failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978976/casting-to-generic-base-class-failing)

Comment: It's impossible to change typed parameter this way.

Comment: What you're doing looks strange to me. I would expect that an pluginsystem has a well defined `IPlugin` which every class has to implement. Going that way you wouldn't have the problems you're describing because you haven't to cast something.

Comment: Tell me about it @user743414, I didn't create this mess ;)  Just trying to sort it out without rewriting it all.  It's looking like I might be able to shoehorn this in using an interface wrapper.

Comment: @tonyenkiducx Here's an older article from codeproject https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1052356/Creating-a-Simple-Plugin-System-with-NET maybe that helps. I do not write the whole stuff again :) Btw. what John wrote looks similar.

Comment: @user743414  Thanks!  The solution for an existing project looks like just adding in an interface at the top level, updating my references to the plugins to use the interface, and then adding to the interface all the elements that are called in the main app.  Changing 1 type out of 9 has generated 1500 errors in VS before it ran out of space, but it's progress :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use contravariance to define your plugin:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var settings = new DerivedSettings()
        {Name = "John"};
        DerivedPlugin a = new DerivedPlugin(settings);
        IPlugin<BaseSettings> sample = (IPlugin<BaseSettings>)a;
        Console.WriteLine(sample.GetName());
    }
}

public abstract class BaseSettings
{
    public abstract string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public interface IPlugin<out TSettings>
    where TSettings : BaseSettings
{
    string GetName();
}

public abstract class BasePlugin<TSettings> : IPlugin<TSettings> where TSettings : BaseSettings
{
    protected readonly TSettings _settings;
    public BasePlugin(TSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return _settings.Name;
    }
}

public class DerivedSettings : BaseSettings
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class DerivedPlugin : BasePlugin<DerivedSettings>
{
    public DerivedPlugin(DerivedSettings settings): base (settings)
    {
    }
}
```

I've included a BasePlugin class, but this is optional and you can just directly use the interface.

Comment: I realise this is terrible, but I'm thinking I'll have to add an interface "wrapper", and then I'd have to cast the plugin to the BasePlugin type when I use it.  It's legacy code....54 projects in a solution....Can't rewrite all of it.

Comment: Marking as answer..  Not marking it as duplicate because I believe this question and answer are better than the other one.  Your answer is much more explicit and shows a solution rather than just pointing to an MSDN article.