# How to use Generics method using Interface in c#? Getting Error

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I have interface with two methods,

I am trying to create the generic interface INewReleaseValidationRule where T : INewReleaseValidationEntity that will have Run() method.

Then I have another class ValidationClass, which is inheriting NewReleaseValidationEntityBase class. I am trying to call the Run() method in ValidateInputMethod() that is in SomeOtherClass. But I am getting error,

**Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Collections.Generic.IList
** 
SalesForecastViewModel is indirectly derived class of INewReleaseValidationEntity, so as per runtime polymorphism it should work?

```
public interface INewReleaseValidationRule<T> where T : INewReleaseValidationEntity
{
    void Run(CtxNewRelease ctx, IList<T> entities);
    string GetMessage(string messageName, string fallbackMessage);
}

public interface INewReleaseValidationEntity
{
    string GetDefaultSkipMsg();
    List<ValidationError> ValidationErrors {get;set;}
    bool Valid { get; set; }
    void SetValidation(string errorCode, string errorMessage, string errorField, Severities severity);
    }

public abstract class NewReleaseValidationEntityBase : INewReleaseValidationEntity
{

    public NewReleaseValidationEntityBase()
    {
        Valid = true;
    }
 //Implementation all the methods of INewReleaseValidationEntity 
}


public class ValidationClass : NewReleaseValidationEntityBase
{
    public ValidationClass()
    {
        MessageHelper.LoadToCache(TYPECODE);
    }

    public string GetMessage(string messageName, string fallbackMessage)
    {
        return MessageHelper.TryGetFromCache(messageName, fallbackMessage);
    }

    public void Run(Context.CtxNewRelease context, IList<INewReleaseValidationEntity> sList)
    {
       //Some code statement to perform validation
    }
}
```

Then I have view model class that is inheriting,

```
public class SalesForecastViewModel : NewReleaseValidationEntityBase
{
   //Some properties and functions
}
```

Then in another class, I am trying to call the generic method Run(),

```
Public Class SomeOtherClass {
     public void ValidateInput(List<SalesForecastViewModel> viewModel)
    {

            ValidationClass vcObject = new ValidationClass();
            **vcObject.Run(context, viewModel);**  //Here viewModel is of child class. It should convert it runtime.

        }
    }
```

}

//Sorry for long confusing code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Generics Inheritance Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909209/c-sharp-generics-inheritance-problem)

Comment: No, this is different. In that example, object shelters 
 is created of same list. Where as I am trying to create the object of child type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is caused by the fact, that the `IList<T>` interface is not covariant. What that really means, is that an `IList<ParentType>` cannot be assigned to an instance of `IList<ChildType>`. The documentation will help you understand the topic more.

So there are two paths you can take here:

1. Use arrays to benefit from implicit reference conversion. Here what the code will look like then:

   `vsObject.Run(context, viewModel.ToArray());`
2. Switch to a covariant interface, which `IEnumerable<T>` is, in your code. So this will require you to change the signature of the `ValidationClass.Run` method as follows:

   `void Run(CtxNewRelease ctx, IEnumerable<T> entities)`

This will make the passed in `List<SalesForecastViewModel>` assignable to a variable of type `IEnumerable<INewReleaseValidationEntity>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Artak, this worked. I am still trying to understand how just adding ToArray() did the trick :). any article to explain this would be helpful.

Comment: Sure. I'll provide more details soon. Sorry, am on phone now